# HighCharts Line Chart Only Display First and Last Marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm currently using a highCharts line chart and I would like to display only the first and last point as a marker on the chart.  Is that possible with any of the configurations?

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({                                           
    global : {
        useUTC : false
    }
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        color: '#000',
    chart:{
        renderTo: 'container',
        margin:[0, 0, 0, 0],
        backgroundColor:'transparent'
    },
    title:{
        text:''
    },
    credits:{
        enabled:false
    },
    xAxis:{
        labels:{
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    yAxis:{
        maxPadding:0,
        minPadding:0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        endOnTick:false,
        labels:{
            enabled:false
        }
    },
    legend:{
        enabled:false
    },
    tooltip:{
        enabled:false
    },
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            enableMouseTracking:false,
            lineWidth:1,
            shadow:false,
            states:{
                hover:{
                    lineWidth:1
                }
            },
            marker:{
                //enabled:false,
                radius:2,
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        radius:2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{type:'line',
        data: [[
                1352740844000,
                12
                ],
                [
                1352741744000,
                10
                ],
                [
                1352742644000,
                20
                ],
                [
                1352743544000,
                40
                ],
                [
                1352744444000,
                50
                ]
         ]
    }] 
 });   
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yoleg24/VhxDA/262/)

I'm currently setting the plotOptions.marker.radius: 2, I'm not sure if any of the other configurations take an index which can determine whether or not to show the marker.

Thanks!

Comment: There are not any existing options to configure this automatically. You can do this by disabling the marker in the plotOptions, and enabling it on the individual point:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/VhxDA/263/

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much!